# Disable Control+Scroll on trackpad with xbindkeys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, touchpad, xbindkeys

I have a problem with Ubuntu **zooming in/out** on Chrome web pages or **enlarging/reducing text size** in code editors whenever I <kbd>scroll</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Control</kbd> (it happens a lot when working with hotkeys so I can't avoid this).

[This article](https://moul.us/disable-ctrl-scroll-zooming-ubuntu/) found a solution using *xbindkeys*, a program that links shell commands (performs certain action) to keys or mouse buttons (on certain hotkey combination, scroll, click) using a configuration file. Basically it "successfully does nothing" when Control + Scrolling by binding <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd> to **/bin/true**. I've done exactly what the article said and (most likely) it doesn't work for trackpads, only mouses. I've emulated Control + Scrolling by holding down <kbd>Control</kbd> and pressing either of the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> and it successfully does nothing (doesn't zoom or enlarge).

So please help me if you know what keycodes to use for trackpad scrolling. I really am frustrated by the sudden zooming to 500% or reducing text to 2pt font size.

Comment: Some solutions to the same issue are discussed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/465965), they do not include the `xbindkeys` solution though.

Comment: Your link (https://moul.us/disable-ctrl-scroll-zooming-ubuntu/) seems dead. :(